# rhythmbox webremote

Tags: rhythmbox, plugins, remote

I would like to control rhythmbox with my android phone and local domestic network. How to use the defaut plugin webremote ? I use Ubuntu 16.04 and rhythmbox 3.4.
I tried to launch the plugin, and then access through a web page with the adress http://local_ip_adress:port_number , but nothing happens. The local ip adress I use is the local ip adress of the computer playing Rhythmbox, and the port number, the port shown by the plugin in "preferences".
Spent a lot of time on the web to find this, no success...
Thank to anybody giving a tuto or explanation :-)

Comment: Did you set an access code in the plugin preferences, and did you click the link "Start web remote"? (My translation.)

Comment: Yes, for both. With or without a code typed in the box, when I click on "start web remote", a web page opens in my browser, with adress :  name_of_my_pc.local:45284/ . But the page is blank. If I type the adress of the machine running rhythmbox with this port from another pc or phone, nothing happens, the page keeps blank. This is the way previous plugins were working, e.g. rhythmweb (that still works, but with very limited functionnalities, and bugs).

Comment: It should work exactly like you describe, and it does on my system. You should get a page (on whichever device you access ipaddress:port) asking you for the access code you set in the preferences. You could try `wget ipaddress:port` in a terminal to see what happens.

Comment: Thnaks for your help ! 
I did it from the computer running rhythmbox, here is what I get with `wget localhost:45284` : 
--2020-09-10 12:05:42--  http://localhost:45284/
Résolution de localhost (localhost)… 127.0.0.1
Connexion à localhost (localhost)|127.0.0.1|:45284… connecté.
requête HTTP transmise, en attente de la réponse… 403 Forbidden
2020-09-10 12:05:42 erreur 403 : Forbidden.
I don't know what to do with it...

Comment: This looks like a firewall issue. Do you use `ufw` or `iptables` ?

Comment: I already thought about it, and I checked with Gufw firewall that my firewall is off.

Comment: Try `sudo netstat -tulpn | grep rhythmbox`. Do you see a listening process there?

Comment: Oups, you left me far behind, I can''t figure out what you make me do ! Here is the result :
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:45284           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      11689/rhythmbox 
tcp6       0      0 :::45284                :::*                    LISTEN      11689/rhythmbox 
Seems like there is a "listenning process", doesn't it ?

Comment: Yes, the `netstat` command lists all processes that listen on the network, and the `grep` command filters out the one that is called `rhythmbox`. So yes, there is a process listening and the port number is correct. Only it doesn't let you connect. What does `sudo iptables -S` give you?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation. Here is the result :
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT